# Ubuntu Customization

Tags: themes, customization

I am beginner on this OS.I ask you to tell me how to customize my desktop or the appearance of this OS on general.I mean these things that you can't do on windows.So i want to learn about softwares that do this kind of job and i want to tell me your current styles in order to try them too.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This [page](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/07/install-malys-inversio-themes-on.html) gives a tutorial on how to install **malys icons and themes**, and I think it would be good to start from here.

As for tweaking, install **MyUnity** with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install myunity
```

You can play with all sorts of things.

Comment: Any theme that you have that found/tried and seems cool,you would mind to share?

Comment: Well, I don't play around with themes on Ubuntu, but I've Faenza Icon Theme (they're really nice!), FS Icons, and malys-icons installed. I also installed one of the malys-theme that I mentioned. Currently I'm using Faenza Icons, and the default theme. You can have a look at the screenshot of my desktop: http://i.imgur.com/M40rm.jpg. It's pretty simple.

Comment: you don't like themes?

Comment: Yes, they're installed, but I use only one - Faenza.

Comment: so why you don't use themes is something wrong with them?

Comment: Nope, I'm not into this aesthetics thing. Although I use themes on Lubuntu.